# Why can I see all the meta review queues but not access any of them?

Tags: bug, review-queue

I understand that I have access to review queues, but not on meta, yet I can access it (presumably because SO's making a decision that I have review queue access on AskUbuntu), but I can't do anything here since I need at least 2k rep.

[image: All review queues listed but greyed out.]

This looks like a bug/unexpected policy config to me.

I know this is an **extremely** minor, first-world problem. :-p

**Can we manage the review queue flag for meta separately from the main site?**

P.S.  I accessed it via here on AskUbuntu:

[image: AskUbuntu review queue menu showing Meta Reviews link.]

But I also noticed that when I'm on the meta site, the menu shows this:

[image: AskUbuntu Meta review queue menu showing "There are no review queues available to you."]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to see the review queues:

- through the drop-down menu at the top right of pages
- [the "all queues" page](https://askubuntu.com/review), which can be accessed by clicking "all queues" in the drop-down menu

For everyone:

- the drop-down menu shows only the queues you have access to
- [the "all queues" page](https://askubuntu.com/review) shows all queues and greys out the queues you don't have access to

There's no real inconsistency, since "all queues" should show all queues.

Comment: That's true, too, but I was actually referring to the "Meta Reviews" link, which shouldn't really be there if you can't access any Meta queues, IMHO.

Comment: The "Meta Queues" link links to the "all queues" page for Ask Ubuntu Meta, so of course it will include all queues.

Comment: Not in my experience.  The "Meta Reviews" link takes me to the page I've screenshotted above which has only Meta queues and all greyed out.

Comment: In your experience, it doesn't show all queues?

Comment: Nope.  It shows what I've screenshotted above.  That's the whole page.

Comment: In the first screenshot, it shows all three queues for Ask Ubuntu Meta.

Comment: That's correct.  I don't have the 2k required to access any of them, so the "Meta Reviews" link shouldn't really be there.  The "all queues" link makes sense, but the "Meta Reviews" link doesn't, IMHO.